# After installing node new version and try to update npm - getting error MODULE_NOT_FOUND in Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

C:\Users\ishara>npm update -g npm
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\ishara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "update" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! node v10.13.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ishara\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 2):

Need to remove old npm folder location in C:\Users\ishara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Comment: Thank you. I had to rename the entire npm folder present under AppData\Roaming to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. My computer name is R&D; and when I install node js, node-module store in it, but when I run "npx create-react-app project-name", it searches node-modules in folder named R (not R&D); So I just copied node-modules from R&D to R (in address which was in cmd (command prompt) and it worked.